# AWS S3 Routing Rule Removed but still works

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have set up routing rules for my S3 bucket. I removed one of the routing rule because I didn't need it anymore and I updated the routing rule policy. So once I removed this one specific rule, I expect it to not redirect or route anymore, right? But it still does it. It still routes or redirects when this specific URL is provided. Why?

Can anybody please tell me what am i missing? By the way... It's been three days I have removed this one specific routing rule for this one specific URL.

The routing rule i have removed:

```
<RoutingRule>
        <Condition>
            <KeyPrefixEquals>content/web/</KeyPrefixEquals>
        </Condition>
        <Redirect>
            <HostName>myHOST</HostName>
            <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>ext/webpage/shownice/</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
        </Redirect>
</RoutingRule>
```

Comment: Did you check that this is not a cache issue?

Comment: It is... :) I don't know why that didn't occur to me. thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should clear your browsers cache.

Comment: Can you please take a look at this, I will really appreciate that. Thanks :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36984411/how-to-fetch-host-name-forwarded-from-s3-to-cloudfront